# Grunt switch task between dev and prod

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a grunt file I am trying to see if I can split so I can call something like `grunt build:dev` or `grunt build:prod`.

Right now the task looks like this -

```
grunt.registerTask('build', "Building all needed files.", [
    'clean:build',
    'check-code',
    'clean:dist',
    'dist:prepare',
    'copy',
    'cssmin',
    'injector',
    'webpack:prod',
    'create-status-page'
]);
```

And I am wondering if there is a way to split this task like you can with configs with a key of `dev` and `prod`, where the task list for prod it slight different than dev. Sort of similiar to how you might do it with tha configs like

```
 return {
    dev: {
     ...
    },
    prod: {
     ...
    }  
 }
```

Is something like this possible? To be clear, I am asking if I can get away with registering both these in a single task.

Comment: So you want to register 2 independent tasks... What's the problem?

Comment: @Amit am wondering if they both can be registered under build in the same function

Comment: But you *do* want to have 2 independent tasks in the end, right?

Comment: Yes, what I am asking however is if they can be combined into 1 function. Perhaps it is not possible, I am just curious.

Comment: 1 *function call*? So that you only call `registerTask` once, but it actually registers 2 tasks?

Comment: Yes exactly, perhaps allow the user to split the task into subtasks via a key (like the configs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use a [multitask](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks).

```
grunt.initConfig({
  build: {
    dev:  ['task1', 'task2', 'task3'],
    prod: ['taskA', 'taskB', 'taskC']
  }
});

grunt.registerMultiTask('build', 'Building...', function() {
  grunt.task.run(this.data);
});
```

Then you can do `grunt build:dev` or `grunt build:prod`

Note: If you just do `grunt build`, it will iterate through all of the properties, so it would run both dev tasks and prod tasks.

Comment: Yes I understand this, what I am asking is if they can be combined and split (by a key perhaps?)

Comment: @ajmajmajma OK, I understand. I think the above answer *may* work.

Comment: Excellent. Good find.